# Send Byte serially using PySerial in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

There a few threads that I have looked through that address similar problems, but have yet to see any for this particular problem.

I am using a PySerial library in Python 3.5 and the program transmits a csv file containing only integer values in the range of 0 -> 2G (giga), which means each integer value can be 1 to 4 bytes.

The built-in Python bin() function works nicely to give me a binary STRING representation of the integer that is to be transmitted. Then I can remove the "0b" at the front of the string in order to transmit the int() value of the remaining string. The problem I am running into is with Pyserial's write() function.

The write() function accepts only sequences (bytesarray, bytes, etc..). If I cast my binary value to bytesarray(), it's going to return an array of values (0-256) of each digit of my binary value, which is not what I want.

When I do any type of encoding, then I can see in Hercules that each bit is being sent as byte. For example,

```
00001000 results in 8 bytes being sent.
Terminal: {30}{30}{30}{30}{31}{30}{30}{30}
```

I have the same problem if I try to transmit a hex value. So my question is, how do I use Pyserial's library to transmit my binary data as a true byte.

If my problem is not clear, just let me know and I'll try to clarify. Essentially, the end result will be:

```
00001000 results in 1 bytes being sent.
Terminal: {08}
```

I made some tweaks to the write() definition to see if I could make it do what I want, but I'm not skilled enough with python to make any major changes. Here is the original definition:

```
def write(self, data):
    """Output the given byte string over the serial port."""
    if not self.is_open:
        raise portNotOpenError
    #~ if not isinstance(data, (bytes, bytearray)):
        #~ raise TypeError('expected %s or bytearray, got %s' (bytes,type(data)))
    # convert data (needed in case of memoryview instance: Py 3.1 io lib), ctypes doesn't like memoryview
    data = to_bytes(data)
    if data:
        #~ win32event.ResetEvent(self._overlapped_write.hEvent)
        n = win32.DWORD()

        success = win32.WriteFile(self._port_handle, data, len(data), ctypes.byref(n), self._overlapped_write)

        if self._write_timeout != 0:  # if blocking (None) or w/ write timeout (>0)
            if not success and win32.GetLastError() != win32.ERROR_IO_PENDING:
                raise SerialException("WriteFile failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))

            # Wait for the write to complete.
            #~ win32.WaitForSingleObject(self._overlapped_write.hEvent, win32.INFINITE)
            win32.GetOverlappedResult(self._port_handle, self._overlapped_write, ctypes.byref(n), True)
            if win32.GetLastError() == win32.ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED:
                return n.value  # canceled IO is no error


            if n.value != len(data):
                raise writeTimeoutError
            return n.value
        else:
            errorcode = win32.ERROR_SUCCESS if success else win32.GetLastError()
            if errorcode in (win32.ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER, win32.ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY,
                             win32.ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED):
                return 0
            elif errorcode in (win32.ERROR_SUCCESS, win32.ERROR_IO_PENDING):
                # no info on true length provided by OS function in async mode
                return len(data)

            else:
                raise SerialException("WriteFile failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> struct.pack('<I', 1234567)
b'\x87\xd6\x12\x00'
>>> struct.pack('>I', 1234567)
b'\x00\x12\xd6\x87'
```

Send one of those, and then read 4 bytes on the other side into a `long`.

Comment: I believe that worked nicely. Thank you. Documentation on the struct library: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)